# What is a Romeo Word™?

Tags: wordplay, pattern, word-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.
Template taken from Rubio.*</sub>

---

Finally made a formal What is a Word puzzle after the Grammy puzzle!

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a ***Romeo Word™***.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.

$$
% set Title text. (spaces around the text ARE important; do not remove.)
% increase Pad value only if your entries are longer than the title bar.
%
\def\Pad{\P{0.0}}  \def\Title{\textbf{ Romeo }}
%
\def\S#1#2{\Space{#1}{20px}{#2px}}\def\P#1{\V{#1em}}\def\V#1{\S{#1}{9}}
\def\T{\Title\textbf{Words}^{\;\!™}\Pad}\def\NT{\Pad\textbf{Not}\T\ }\displaystyle
\smash{\lower{29px}\bbox[yellow]{\phantom{\rlap{rubio.2019.05.15}\S{6px}{0}
\begin{array}{cc}\Pad\T&\NT\\\end{array}}}}\atop\def\V#1{\S{#1}{5}}
\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline\Pad\T&\NT\\\hline
%
\text{  achieve         }&\text{        obtain          }\\ \hline
\text{  amphibian       }&\text{        reptile         }\\ \hline
\text{  audiotape       }&\text{        cassette        }\\ \hline
\text{  collapsing      }&\text{        erect           }\\ \hline
\text{  cytomegalic     }&\text{        retinitis       }\\ \hline
\text{  emu             }&\text{        ostrich         }\\ \hline
\text{  epsilon         }&\text{        echo            }\\ \hline
\text{  labdanum        }&\text{        oakmoss         }\\ \hline
\text{  metal           }&\text{        plastic         }\\ \hline
\text{  neighborhood    }&\text{        family          }\\ \hline
\text{  numerical       }&\text{        text            }\\ \hline
\text{  parasigmatism   }&\text{        pronounce       }\\ \hline
\text{  restaurant      }&\text{        inn             }\\ \hline
\text{  toxic           }&\text{        poisonous       }\\ \hline
\text{  typothetae      }&\text{        printers        }\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Bonus Question:

> What's wrong with the title?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I bet a Romeo Word™ is one which

> contains a Greek alphabet letter

The table taught as:

> a**chi**eve
>  am**phi**bian
>  aud**iota**pe
>  colla**psi**ng
>  cyt**omega**lic
>  e**mu**
>  e**psi**lon - a double Romeo Word™
>  labda**nu**m
>  m**eta**l
>  neighbo**rho**od
>  **nu**merical
>  para**sigma**tism
>  res**tau**rant
>  to**xi**c
>  typo**theta**e - a double Romeo Word™

What's wrong with the title?

> Perhaps because Romeo contains an Italian capital, and not a Greek letter.

Comment: Dang, a well formatted answer and still beat me by 2 minutes.  Nice solve!

Comment: @TwoBitOperation - I think your answer explains the title better, all I thought of later is the Nato alphabet letter for d would have been more suitable than r.

Comment: well done! check is on its way :)

Answer (score 18):

A romeo word:

> **Contains a Greek letter**
> chi, phi, iota, psi, omega, mu, epsilon, nu, eta, rho, nu, sigma, tau, xi, theta

Edit:  Beaten by @Tom

My guess as to the bonus:

> 'Romeo' would need to be spelt 'Rhomeo' to conform to the rules?

Comment: rot13([Eubzrb l Whyvrgn](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romeo_y_Julieta)) `:)`

Comment: TwoBitOperation, will you accept a +100rep bounty offer to compensate for a green tick, given that you have the correct and intended answer, yet you were sniped by 2 minutes? :)

Comment: That's kind of you! I was beaten fair and square, it's all good.

Comment: @MrPie How dare you give away bounties, rep's not happy with you >:)